# unable to create new android application in eclipse after upgrade

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

In eclipse Helios I have upgraded my android plugin and android sdk to recent version.After the upgrade i am unable to create the new android app
this is the screen shot of the error message i got
[image]

Comment: just click on Install/Upgrade

Comment: Delete the existing Android Support Library(located under Extras) and redownload it.Then try to create a project.It will work.

Comment: even i click on install/upgrade the problem still exists. i have created new directory support under extras\android and deleted all files under compatibility   and upgraded the sdk now every thing works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is listed in code.google.com 
Here is the [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33859)
The work around commented by jaisonDavis is worked for me. (*also suggested in code.google.com*)

- Open the **sdk manager** and **Delete the existing Android Support Library**
  its *located under the extras*
- Create a **new project** and  **Install the support library by clicking on
  "Install / Upgrade"**

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete the Support library, Go the SDK_Folder/extra/android and rename the folder compatibility to support. After that, restart the Eclipse.